# Android how initialize activity RecyclerView Scrollbars INVERTED to BOTTOM?

Tags: android

How to keeping the position of the "scrollbars" in RecyclerView when you receive new data? For example, Whatsapp?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewchatView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/botaoenviar"/>


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {... 
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() -1);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getDataUsuarioDestino();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handler.postDelayed( this, 3000 );
        }
    },  3000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

This solution is create a count of the recyclerview adapter size and set manualy in the scrollposition

```
int recyclerposition = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerposition-1);
```